# Grails Resources render resources for disposition [defer] Warning?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, gsp

Using the Grails Resources plugin I get the following warning when I try to load Ajax content into my page:

```
 WARN  resource.ResourceTagLib  - A request was made to render resources for 
   disposition [defer] but there are no resources scheduled for that disposition, 
   or it has already been rendered
```

What does this mean and how can I solve the?

For my ajax content I use a special **ajax.gsp** template:

```
<g:layoutBody/>
<r:layoutResources disposition="defer"/>
```

In the controller that renders the ajax request I do:

```
if (request.xhr) {
  render template: 'myView', model:[user: user], layout: 'ajax'
}
```

What do I have to change to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Are you using any js inside your ajax template? If so put them in <r:script> tag and at the end of the template

Comment: If you write it as an answer I can apply it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any js inside your ajax template? If so put them in `<r:script>` tag and at the end of the template.

Hope it helps

Comment: I still have the warning. Any other idea?